# Sun Solaris Server Voltage issue

Tags: solaris

I have a sun solaris server which die off recently due to voltage issue

Checking with sun solaris support personnel the cost is like 5k or 6k per maintence year support.

I am wondering whether it is worth the price or should i instead purchase a new solaris server and redo the setup etc.

Any advise anyone?

And also is there anyaway i can remove the harddisk in the existing solaris server and put into the new server?

Comment: Without knowing your hardware and Solaris  configuration we can't begin to answer your question.

Comment: Sun T1000 Server

Answer (score 1):

Your question looks like asking "my old car which is no more under warranty broke its engine. What's the best option, buy a new one or buy a support contract to have it repaired ?"

I'm afraid the latter option won't work as you generally cannot have support contracts be retroactive.

Buying a used T1000 on ebay and switching the power supply might be the cheaper alternative if you are on a budget. Otherwise, buying a current generation server might be better compared to a older box performance.

Comment: Watch out for any hostid based software licensing. The hostid will change when you get a new chassis.

Comment: Indeed, one of the reasons why I suggested swapping the power supply. The hostid is hopefully not stored on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a power supply for that for around $500.  It's not very difficult to install it.  The server itself is only a few years old and can run $2500+, so you'd still be ahead.  For the other question, you can usually just pop the disks out and put them in the new system.

I remember having issues using an existing Disksuite configuration when the device paths changed due to different hardware.  That's relatively easy to fix if they're plain mirrors just by creating a new configuration starting with one side of the mirror.